# Rails accessing a shared custom validation in a module within a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to figure out how to create a shared custom validation that I can use across my models that I've placed within a lib/validations.rb folder.

```
module Validations
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # included do


  def email_format_validation
    if self.email.present?
      if !validates_format_of :email, with: email_regex
        self.errors.add(:email, "doesn't exist")
      end
    end
  end


  def email_regex
    /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
  end
end
```

So in my model, this allows me to do:

```
validate :email_format_validation
```

In other models, I'm trying to just call `email_regex`:

```
validate :user_email, with: email_regex
```

which produces the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `email_regex' for #<Class....>
```

I've tried using `include Validations`, `extend Validations`, `require 'validations'`, etc. in my model with no luck. I've also tried placing the module methods within a `class << self`, using the `included do` block, setting the methods as `self.email_regex` and calling `Validations.email_regex` and yet nothing seems to work.

Comment: Check the guide on custom validator https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators. You can create a class extending ActiveModel::Validator instead of using a concern and use validates_with.

Comment: can you try moving the file `validations.rb` to `app/models/concerns` folder and try adding `include Validations` in your model

Comment: @Nandhini I actually initially had it in concerns prior to moving it and had the same issue

Comment: @asalgan have posted my answer. It worked for me. Try the same and let me know if any issue persists.

Comment: @Nandhini actually I realized this doesn't solve my issue when the class doesn't inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` if it's a standalone class then I still encounter the issue above, any idea as to why that's happening?

Comment: @asalgan it worked for me without the inheritance. what is the rails version that you are using?

Comment: @Nandhini im on 5.1.6

Comment: @asalgan I checked in 5.2.2 and it was an API only application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried the following and it worked for me:

Created validations.rb in models/concerns

```
module Validations
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def email_format_validation
    if self.email.present?
      if !validates_format_of :email, with: email_regex
        self.errors.add(:email, "doesn't exist")
      end
    end
  end


  def email_regex
    /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
  end
end
```

In the model:

```rb
include Validations

class User < ApplicationRecord
  validate :email_format_validation
  validates :user_email, with: :email_regex
end
```

user_email is the field name

Comment: apparently I was using `validate` instead of `validates` - it also worked when I did `validates_format_of` whoops! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of Rails 3, you may also use [validates_with](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-with):

```rb
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.email.present?
      if !email_regex.match?(record.email)
        record.errors.add(:email, "is invalid")
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def email_regex
    /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates_with EmailValidator
end
```

This allows you to e.g. easily make the field name dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using require_relative Validations